# Diferencias entre Date, DateTime y Calendar en Java 7

Tags: java

Estoy usando Java 7 para desarrollar una aplicación para agendar conferencias.

He visto que hay varios tipos de datos para manejar las fechas.

Ejemplo:

```
private Date creationDate;

private DateTime creationDate;

private Calendar creationDate;
```

Mi pregunta es: **¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el tipo `Calendar`, `Date` y `DateTime`?**

Comment: En esta pregunta de Stack Overflow en inglés se habla de las diferencias entre Date y Calendar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404210/java-date-vs-calendar En cuanto a Datetime, me parece que es similar a Date pero más actualizada. Quizá alguien con mayor conocimiento te puede indicar mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la documentación de [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (traducido):

> La clase `Date` representa un instante específico en el tiempo, con precisión de milisegundos.

Mientras que [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (traducido, énfasis mía):

> La clase `Calendar` es una **clase abstracta** que provee métodos para convertir entre un específico instante en el tiempo y un conjunto de campos de calendario como YEAR (año), MONTH (mes), DAY_OF_MONTH (día del mes), HOUR (hora) y así, y para manipular los campos del calendario, como obtener la fecha de la próxima semana.

El mayor problema acá en el diseño de la clase `Date` es que es mutable, cuando debió ser inmutable y la operación sobre fechas como aumentar (o disminuir) días, horas, segundos, años, etc, y generación de `Date`s debería ser a través de `Calendar`. Al menos esta es la forma en que suelo trabajar para evitar problemas al manejar los datos de `Date`. En Java 8 esto se *resolvió* al implementar un nuevo framework interno para manejo de fechas y horas llamado [Java 8 Date and Time](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) y las clases se pueden encontrar bajo el paquete `java.time` (tu pregunta es en base a Java 7, así que solo menciono esta parte de Java 8, no ahondaré más en este punto).

Para usar `Calendar`, te recomiendo siempre inicializarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Puesto que hay más de una implementación de `Calendar`, siendo la más conocida (y utilizada) `GregorianCalendar`, pero también están [`BuddhistCalendar`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/util/BuddhistCalendar.html) y [`JapaneseImperialCalendar`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/JapaneseImperialCalendar.java.html) (al menos desde el código de Open JDK). El método `Calendar#getInstance` delega la creación del calendario al método `createCalendar` que para Java 8 está implementado de la siguiente manera (revisando el código fuente de HotSpot):

```
private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone zone,
                                       Locale aLocale)
{
    CalendarProvider provider =
        LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(CalendarProvider.class, aLocale)
                             .getCalendarProvider();
    if (provider != null) {
        try {
            return provider.getInstance(zone, aLocale);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // fall back to the default instantiation
        }
    }

    Calendar cal = null;

    if (aLocale.hasExtensions()) {
        String caltype = aLocale.getUnicodeLocaleType("ca");
        if (caltype != null) {
            switch (caltype) {
            case "buddhist":
            cal = new BuddhistCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            case "japanese":
                cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            case "gregory":
                cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cal == null) {
        // If no known calendar type is explicitly specified,
        // perform the traditional way to create a Calendar:
        // create a BuddhistCalendar for th_TH locale,
        // a JapaneseImperialCalendar for ja_JP_JP locale, or
        // a GregorianCalendar for any other locales.
        // NOTE: The language, country and variant strings are interned.
        if (aLocale.getLanguage() == "th" && aLocale.getCountry() == "TH") {
            cal = new BuddhistCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        } else if (aLocale.getVariant() == "JP" && aLocale.getLanguage() == "ja"
                   && aLocale.getCountry() == "JP") {
            cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        } else {
            cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
        }
    }
    return cal;
}
```

Recomiendo siempre trabajar con `Calendar` porque se considera buena práctica trabajar con clases abstractas e interfaces en lo posible por sobre trabajar con la implementación directamente. Esto se cubre acá (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197

No conozco ninguna clase `DateTime` declarada en el JDK 7. Quizás te refieres a la clase `org.joda.time.DateTime` de la librería [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (nombre curioso en español), la cual surge como una solución para evitar trabajar con `Date` que es mutable. `DateTime` es inmutable y las operaciones que realices sobre un `DateTime` en realidad crearán una nueva instancia de `DateTime` en lugar de modificar la instancia actual.

---

Si quieres saber cuál clase debes utilizar en tus proyectos, te daría las siguientes recomendaciones:

- Para tus entidades, declara los campos de tipo `Date` (asegúrate que sean del paquete `java.util`).
- Para realizar operaciones sobre `Date` como agregar o quitar tiempo, existen 2 opciones:

  - Crea un objeto de tipo `Calendar`, seteas su tiempo desde una instancia de `Date` vía `Calendar#setTime`, realizas las operaciones necesarias, y obtienes el `Date` de `Calendar` vía `Calendar#getTime`.
  - Procedimiento similar al descrito anteriormente, pero utilizando `DateTime` de Joda.
- Si quieres representar una fecha y hora de manera textual, te recomiendo utilizar [`SimpleDateFormat#format(Date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) (ojo, recibe `Date` y no `Calendar`)  y evitar usar los métodos `Date#getXyz`. También podrías utilizar `Calendar#get(Calendar.<campo>)` pero el código sería muy *verbose* (no sé una traducción de esto).

¿Por qué no declarar directamente el uso de `DateTime` en los campos de tus entidades? Pues porque hay frameworks que no soportan la conversión directa a menos que implementes convertores particulares para ello. Algunos ejemplos: Hibernate<sup>1</sup>, JSF, Spring, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hibernate 5 ahora ofrece soporte para la librería Date Time de Java 8. Supongo que los frameworks poco a poco irán yendo por ese camino también en algún momento.

Answer (score 3):

Los objetos de tipo `Date` en Java se utilizan para representar un instante específico en el tiempo. También permite convertir y *parsear* fechas sin embargo los métodos que proporcionaban esto ahora están *deprecated*.

En su lugar se ocupa la clase `Calendar` para conversiones y aritmética de fechas, esta clase también proporciona la habilidad de trabajar con distintos `Locales` y representar fechas en distintos lenguajes o tipos de calendario específico.

Convertir objetos `Date` a `Calendar` es sencillo:

```
Date d = new Date();  // Crea el objeto Date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Obtiene una instancia de Calendar
calendar.setTime(date); // Asigna la fecha al Calendar
```

Una vez que tienes una instancia de `Calendar` puedes obtener información acerca de la fecha de la siguiente forma:

```
int year        = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month       = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int weekOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Una cosa que hay que tomar en cuenta es que los meses se consideran enteros de 0 a 11. En la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) puedes encontrar todos los campos disponibles que puedes consultar.

Si tienes una instancia de `Calendar` y quieres convertir a fecha:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date =  calendar.getTime();
```

Para *parseo* y dar formato a fechas se recomienda usar la clase `DateFormat` o alguna subclase como `SimpleDateFormat`, por ejemplo:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String fecha = sdf.format(new Date()); 
System.out.println(fecha); // 27/01/2016
```

Mi sugerencia es que almacenes tus fechas como objetos `Date` porque son objetos más fáciles de generar y si necesitas alguna conversión u operación como añadir 5 meses a una fecha utilices `Calendar` y luego vuelvas al tipo `Date`.

Por último `DateTime` no es un tipo de dato en Java SE, existe como parte de una biblioteca llamada [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), y ofrece una variedad de métodos adicionales para operar con fechas.